# How can I apply table structure to select box options in HTML

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, width, html-select

In my select box options, each option having three words.Now I want apply fixed widths for each word of the option so that the all options will come as i required
for example My options are as follows :

```
1,   aaaaa bbbbb ccccccccc
2,   aaaaaaaa bbbbbbb cccc     
3,   aaaaaa bbbbb cccc
```

but i want to display these options in the dropdown as

```
1,   aaaaa     bbbbb     ccccccccc
2,   aaaaaaaa  bbbbbbb   cccc     
3,   aaaaaa    bbbbb     cccc
```

help me if anyone know how to do this

Comment: Are you asking how to set the width of a select field?

Comment: Am i missing it or do I not see a difference in both the options...

Comment: Ah. James' edit made things more clear. You want a table structure inside your select options.

Comment: Have you tried putting your options inside div's and styling them according to your needs?

Comment: I suspect that that would not be valid HTML. Checking...

Comment: Nope. "Permitted content: Zero or more <option> or <optgroup> elements." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/select

Comment: the key here is how you construct the select box options - where do the values come from?

Comment: Oh..Thanks Mr.James. This is the format required for my select box options

Comment: The only way to do this would be to use spaces!

Comment: Sorry to inform you..options are taken from database only

Comment: ah, but which database, and by what means? (php/asp/jsp) - you may be able to pad the values before you output them in the page. that might be preferable to tinkering with the values via javascript later.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `div` and `CSS` style .See this sample that i wrote in jsfiddle.net
[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/talebihamid/ykW8M/11/)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to 1) apply a monospace font to select options, and 2) use JavaScript to make sure each element of an option has the same number of characters by adding trailing spaces as needed, either to some arbitrary length or to the length of the longest element.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to use a third-party JavaScript library to restructure the select box and add styling as needed.

http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/